# crontab failing to start service via working script

Tags: ubuntu, cron

My script works when ran by itself but not via crontab

### Crontab

```
[root@someserver:/]# crontab -l
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/home/ec2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /opt/scripts/check_beaver_status.sh
```

### Script in question

```
#!/bin/bash

function check_if_beaver_running () {
        current_script=`basename $0`
        process_name="beaver"
        /bin/ps aux | /bin/grep "${process_name}" | /bin/grep -v 'grep' | /bin/grep -v "$current_script"

         if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
             echo "${process_name} running"
         else
             echo "${process_name}: not running, starting..."
             if [ -f /var/run/logstash_beaver.pid ] ; then
                         /bin/rm -f /var/run/logstash_beaver.pid
             fi
             /sbin/service beaver start
         fi
}
check_if_beaver_running
```

Comment: do you see that the job is being triggered in /var/log/cron every minute?

Comment: That script kinda looks like it should be replaced by monit.

Comment: I run beaver and stunnel via supervisor.  If in python, do as in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crond wasn't running.

```
[root@someserver:]# service crond status
crond is stopped

[root@someserver:]# service crond start

[root@someserver:]# chkconfig crond on
```

Also I changed my script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
# when running in crontab:
# SHELL=/bin/bash
# PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
# */10 * * * * /bin/bash beaver_ensure_running.sh

START=false
readarray -t PIDS < <(exec pgrep -x beaver)

function stop_beaver {
    /usr/sbin/service beaver stop
    sleep 5s  ## Optionally wait for processes to stop.
    kill -s SIGTERM "${PIDS[@]}" ## Perhaps force another signal to them if it doesn't work with defuncts.
    sleep 5s  ## Optionally wait for processes to stop.
    kill -s SIGKILL "${PIDS[@]}" ## Perhaps force another signal to them if it doesn't work with defuncts.
    START=true
}
if [[ ${#PIDS[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "No beaver process was found."
    START=true
elif [[ ${#PIDS[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "Processes found: ${PIDS[*]}"
    echo "Only one beaver process found."
    stop_beaver
elif ps -fp "${PIDS[@]}" | fgrep -F '<defunct>' >/dev/null; then
    echo "Processes found: ${PIDS[*]}"
    echo "Defunct beaver process found."
    stop_beaver
else
    echo "Processes found: ${PIDS[*]}"
fi
[[ $START == true ]] && /usr/sbin/service beaver start
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm very interested in the answer to this, so let me help you diagnose it.

Try changing cron to:

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash -x /opt/scripts/check_beaver_status.sh > /tmp/crondiag.log 2>&1
```

Also add the command:

```
env
```

To both the top of the script, and the bottom of the function call in the script.

Let it run once and share with us the result.  Maybe on pastie.org or something.